# Replacing the equality operator (==) with the identity operator (===) in Vim

Tags: vim, sed

I want to change all occurrences of `==` to `===`, but issuing the command `:%s/==/===/g` would convert existing identity operators from `===` to `====`. I tried using the command `:%s/\<==\>/===/g`, but no pattern matches are found.

Comment: `\<` and `\>` don't work as expected because `=` is not a "word" character, hence the word boundary markers do not match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

kind of ugly, but `:%s/\([^=]\)==\([^=]\)/\1===\2/g`

**EDIT**

Turned out that ib. has far better solution so look at his answer.  That takes care of the cases of `!==` etc.  So ignore this one and look at his.

Comment: In the interest of learning about regular expressions, can you explain what that does? (also, the command does not work for me).

Comment: `\( \)` parts hold onto what was there and then retrieve that later by `\1` and `\2`.  every pair of `\( \)` you use you are gonna get \1, \2 and so on.  in this case i saved a char before == and one after.  but for each of them i used `[^=]`, which means any character except `=`.  with `[]`, you can list characther you want ot pick, and `^` being the first in the list, you negate your list.  I think many different variety of regex support this notation

Comment: This command only works if there are two (possibly blank) characters around the `==`. I realize no one will put `==` at the beginning of a line, or have it at the end of a line (or both). I'm just pointing this out

Comment: @puk: you are right....  i dont do c, c++, java, javascript, those kind of flexible format language much, so my implicit assumption maybe not be good.  may need to look a line before and line follow, if that can be an issue, and make expression even uglier.  i'd blame the original coder, though :p.

Comment: I don't know what happened, but when I issued the command `:bufdo %s/\([^=]\)==\([^=]\)/\1===\2/ge | update` `!===` started popping up everywhere. Thank god for revert.

Comment: This command does not substitute every occurrence of `==`: those `==` that are the very first or the very last characters on a line, are left untouched!

Comment: @yosukesabai:  Yes, in that sense, it does.  Unlike this substitution command, the one I propose in my answer to the question, works in all cases.  It replaces described occurrences of `==` located at the very beginning or the very ending of a line, too.  Try both and see for yourself.

Comment: @puk:  That is probably because of the pattern which also matches a `!==` operator existing in some programming languages.  See my answer for a possible solution.

Comment: @ib yes I came to that conclusion too. What I did was simply convert all identities `===` to equalities `==` then issue the command `:%s/==/===/g`. The equality operator is (almost) completely inferior to the identity operator.

Answer (score 6):

The informal definition of the pattern given in the question could be
read as *“two equal signs in a row neither preceded with nor followed
by an equal sign”*.

A natural way to transform this verbal description to a concise Vim
regular expression is to use the `\@<!` and `\@!` zero-width assertions
(see `:help /multi` for an overview). The former allows to leave out
the occurrences starting with a certain pattern (see `:help /\@<!`).
The latter makes it possible to ignore the occurrences ending with an
ineligible pattern (see `:help /\@!`).

```
:%s/=\@<!===\@!/&=/g
```

As far as I can guess from the history of your questions and answers
on StackOverflow, the substitution is probably to be performed in
JavaScript or PHP source code. Since both languages have the `!==`
inequality operator as well as the `===` equality one, `==` in the
former is also the subject of replacement as you describe it in the
question. If this behavior is undesirable, modify the substitution
command above, as follows:

```
:%s/[!=]\@<!===\@!/&=/g
```

Comment: [`\@<!`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C@%3C!) and [`\@!`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C@!) and ...  what is `&` in the replacement part, please?

Comment: @yosukesabai:  The matched pattern substitution (see `:help s/\&`).

Comment: +1; For reference these are called "zero-width assertions".  Also +1 for the psychic pre-emptive debugging of the `!==` issue :)

Answer (score 2):

Consider adding the `c` flag on the sed command: `%s/==/===/gc`

This will allow you to choose every time with `y` or `n`. Of course if there are a lot then this might not be the best plan.

Comment: I know the basics, and generally I would agree with you, but there are 44 matches for `==` and I have a few hundred files.